# Moving button in front of other panels

Tags: java, swing, animation, layout

I'm coding a simple card-based game where the player has a hand of cards along the bottom of the screen. When they click on a card, the card moves across the window onto a 'discard pile' location.

I've got the movement animation working to my satisfaction, but the problem is the card button disappears when it moves across other panels. The hand of cards is in the PAGE_END section of a borderlayout for the content pane, and the discard pile is at the top of the screen - so the card has to move across the CENTER section to get to its destination. But it goes *behind* the CENTER panel, whereas I want it to go in front.

Is this possible? I've tried looking into LayeredPanes but that seems to require all of my components being directly inside one container, which they aren't (because I have another panel inside the bottom section of my content panel).

I've written up the simplest version of the problem that I can, using two classes.

The main class:

```
package moveButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class MoveButton extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public JPanel view;
    public MovingButton mover;
    public static MoveButton instance;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        instance = new MoveButton();
    }

    public MoveButton() {

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setVisible(true);

        view = new JPanel();
        view.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        view.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        mover = new MovingButton("Move");
        mover.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(mover);

        this.setContentPane(view);

        this.repaint();
        this.revalidate();



    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        MoveButton.instance.mover.timer.start();
    }

}
```

The button class:

```
package moveButton;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MovingButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    public Timer timer;
    public static final int X_INC = 5;
    public static final int Y_INC = -5;
    public int xPos;
    public int yPos;



public MovingButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        timer = new Timer(30, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        this.move();
        MoveButton.instance.repaint();

        if(xPos == 100 || yPos == 100) {
            timer.stop();
        }

    }

    public void move() {
        xPos = xPos + X_INC;
        yPos = yPos + Y_INC;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.translate(xPos, yPos);
        super.paint(g);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you starting a Swing Timer from within a background thread, a thread guaranteed not to be on the Swing event thread?

Comment: Myself, I'd elevate any images that I want to move across the GUI onto the glass pane, and then place back into the GUI proper when done moving.

Comment: See the [Glass Pane Demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) from the Swing tutorial for an example of painting on the glass pane.

Comment: @HoverCraft Full Of Eels I'm not certain what you mean about the Swing timer and event thread. I'm very much a newbie and I get that my technique in general might not be great, but for now I'm just looking for help specifically on the problem of moving a component in front of other containers. I will have a look into using the Glass Pane, thanks both for that tip.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get rid of that SwingWorker as it definitely does not belong there.  Instead simply start the Swing Timer in place from within the ActionListener.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks, I've edited my post with the neatened code. I think I initially tried to do it this way but must have made a mistake because I thought it didn't work (which is why I then added the SwingWorker) - oh well.

Comment: As myself and @camickr have mentioned, you need to read up on the glasspane and use it. This will guarantee that a component is above all other components.